# Elasticsearch searching a subset of nested objects with simple_query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have the following data format:

```
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "publications": [
    {
      "category": "cat-aaa",
      "text": "car airplane boat"
    },
    {
      "category": "cat-bbb",
      "text": "pen chain headphones"
    },
    {
      "category": "cat-ccc",
      "text": "mouse screen computer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now, I am using `simple_query_string` to search across the `publications.text` field. A query  such as `car AND mouse` would return the document above.

What I want is to search for people by publications' texts, but only for some categories. For instance, a query `car AND mouse` searching through categories `cat-aaa` and `cat-ccc` should return the above document. However, searching for `car AND mouse` through category `cat-aaa` should not match the above document.

The two approaches that I have tried so far did not work:

1. Without using nested queries it's not possible to filter publications as ES is flattening the data.
2. When using nested queries, I cannot search across all the publications of a person, so the query example from above wouldn't work. Nested queries seem to process individual nested documents, but I need to search across all nested documents matching the category I choose.

Can such a query be done using ES ?

Comment: a query `car AND mouse` searching through categories cat-aaa and cat-ccc should return the above document. ----> do you mean `car OR mouse`

Comment: @SagarPatel, I mean AND. Without using category filters, the AND query works because ES is flattening publications.text, but this trick does not work when using nested documents.